# UITextView caret jump to the end when insert a new NSAttribuitedString

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitextview

I'm working with UITextView and trying to achieve ol/ul editor in this view .... Here is how it works so far

[image: Work with normal Caret]

Our editor first translate HTML content into NSAttributedString, with these content, it works fine

```html
<ol>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
</ol>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<ol>
    <li>abcdef</li>
    <li>abcdef</li>
    <li>abcdef</li>
</ol>
```

However when we add just some simple text on top of the content, here comes the weird behavior.

[image: Not work and caret jump wrong]

As you can see, the caret will jump to the end after the new ordered line and when I press a key. Look like it's trying to reset the style of the row i made before

Here is the HTML content that it will translate.

```html
Just some text on top
<ol>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
</ol>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
    <li>123456</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<ol>
    <li>abcdef</li>
    <li>abcdef</li>
    <li>abcdef</li>
</ol>
```

One thing i did notice that every time i make a new ordered line and enter a key, it will try to reformat the styles of my current ol, which will make the attributedText of the control change. The problem is I don't know where is this coming from. Any knowledge regarding to this one will be really helpful

Comment: Are you using Swift? Can you show your code that works with `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: i'm not using Swift unfortunately .... i'm using Xamarin, but it's very similar to Swift, i will try to make a repo in Swift if possible to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turn out it's another Xamarin weird behavior ....

The problem is i'm inheriting from, in their EditorRenderer, they have codes that transform Characters Spacing property that will updates AttributedText in every code changes!

So that's why after everytime I add new text (the prefix 1.,2.,3. ....) programmatically, it will trigger that text change and then trigger then AttributedText! Took me hours to figure out

Here is the code that they implemented in their base class.

```
        protected internal override void UpdateCharacterSpacing()
    {
        var textAttr = TextView.AttributedText.AddCharacterSpacing(Element.Text, Element.CharacterSpacing);

        if(textAttr != null)
            TextView.AttributedText = textAttr;

        var placeHolder = _placeholderLabel.AttributedText.AddCharacterSpacing(Element.Placeholder, Element.CharacterSpacing);

        if(placeHolder != null)
            _placeholderLabel.AttributedText = placeHolder;
    }
```